# Build Error Installing Macaulay2 on Arch Linux

Tags: linux, build, macaulay2

When running makepkg for [Macaulay2](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/macaulay2?all_deps=1&O=0), I get the following error:

```
+ rm -f '/home/user-name/macaulay2/src/M2/M2/usr-host/lib/*.la'
/usr/bin/install -c -d /home/user-name/macaulay2/src/M2/M2/usr-host/bin
/usr/bin/install: cannot create directory ‘/home/user-name/macaulay2/src/M2/M2/usr-host/bin’: File exists
make[2]: *** [../Makefile.library:135: .installed-6.2.0] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user-name/macaulay2/src/M2/M2/libraries/csdp'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:7: all-in-csdp] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user-name/macaulay2/src/M2/M2/libraries'
make: *** [GNUmakefile:251: all-in-libraries] Error 2
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
Aborting...
```

What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably too late for the answer and the problem is solved, but for future readers who come across this question by accident:
The error message you encountered suggests that the M2 directory already exists and cannot be created again during the build process. This issue can occur if you have previously attempted to build Macaulay2 and the directory was not properly cleaned up.
So, remove the existing directory. And reinstall M2.

p.s: For Macaulay2 questions, I recommend you to ask in [its own Google group.](https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/macaulay2/)